# C++ if Followed by a for Loop block

Tags: c++, if-statement

I remember once I've seen somebody writing C++ code like this:

```
if (something is true)
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        //do something
        line 1;
        line 2;
        line 3;
        ....
        ....
    }
else
    ....
```

It works the same as the following code:

```
if (something is true) {  //note the bracket here
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        //do something
        line 1;
        line 2;
        line 3;
        ....
        ....
    }
}
else
    ....
```

I'm wondering if the compiler treated the `for` loop block as one line nested within the `if` clause? Can the multiple lines of code within bracket always be treated as one line? I can't quite understand how does the compiler parse and analyse this.

Comment: If you don't put a `{}` scope resolution operator after the control structure, then it evaluates the next line as it's scope. Since the for loop, does use the `{}` then it is treated as one scope/block. It's pretty horrible practice, though, in my opinion, to omit the `{}` when the next line is going to have a multi-line block.

Comment: the short answer is yes, but brackets help to better read your code

Comment: Maybe, not 100% sure, but it is a bad idea. You could probably read it, but God help anyone else trying to.

Comment: @crush but actually it executes the whole `for` loop block, how do you explain the meaning of "line". This is my point.

Comment: @Dreamer It executes the next line's scope. That means anything within `{}` is a nested scope, so everything within that scope gets executed.

Comment: @crush Stop calling `{}` scope resolution operators, please. They're not.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. `::` is scope resolution operator. What the hell are these called besides `curly-brackets`?

Comment: They don't have any other name by themselves, AFAIK.

Comment: It's called a [**compound statement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce4b8s02.aspx) or block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed correct code, although it may easily confuse readers. The `if`-statement considers the first following statement as it's `then` statement. Code between `{}` is usually considered a block or compound statement, containing the statements within it. Similarly, the `for` statement is considered one statement, including the loop body, which is the first statement to follow it (and can again be a block).

Comment: You don't need to say "considered" here.  `{ stmt* }` _is_ a single statement.  So is `for ( ... ) stmt`.  So is `if ( condition ) stmt`.  Putting the first two together, `for (...) { stmt* }` is a statement, and then so is `if ( condition ) for (...) { stmt* }`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first case runs fine because the `if` statement without brackets considers the next single statement(`for` loop)as a part of its body to be executed. The body of the for loop is a part of the loop itself.

If there had been no brackets for the loop itself, then only the first statement of the loop would have been executed.

Answer (score 2):

They are not really "lines" but rather statements. For instance your

```
line 1;
line 2;
line 3;
```

could be rewritten as and would be just as valid as:

```
line 1; line 2; line 3;
```

So the compiler is not really looking at lines but rather statements.

A single statement as defined by the grammar is considered either (somewhat simplified):

1) a simple statement terminated by a semicolon (as above)

OR

2) as a statement-block which is one or more simple statements enclosed within brackets `{}`.

Comment: `if (false) print("test"); print("test");` Should only print a single "test" right? Even though they are on the same line? I felt like your opening argument didn't make this clear.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I was trying to not go too deep into the actual grammar rules.

Comment: @DaveRager It's not going too deep to point out that newlines are just white space (once we've finished pre-processing), and have _no_ effect on the language.

Answer (score 2):

`{}` defines a [**compound statement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce4b8s02.aspx) or block.

> With the introduction of control structures we are going to have to
>   introduce a new concept: the compound-statement or block. A block is a
>   group of statements which are separated by semicolons (;) like all C++
>   statements, but grouped together in a block enclosed in braces: { }:
>
> *From cplusplus.com: [Control Structures](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)*

The `if` control structure is defined as follows:

```
if (condition) statement
```

That `statement` can be defined as a single instruction/statement, or a `compound statement`. Either way, it's the next statement to be executed.

`for (;;) statement` is a special type of control structure called an *iteration structure*.

Therefore,

```
//The control structure is going to apply to the next statement
if (condition)
    for (;;) //This for loop is the next statement. It applies to the next statement.
    {
        //The next statement is a compound statement.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if there are no brackets after the if-statement it will just process the next line if the conditions are true. Since the next line was a for statement, it treats it as one command.